# How to get the Go to Definition feature in VSCode working for absolute imports?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, import, go-to-definition

In general, Go to Definition feature does work in my VSCode, however, in the below case

```
varshini@dell:~/src/loan-predictions$ tree
.
|-- Makefile
|-- README.md
|-- requirements.txt
|-- setup.py
`-- loan_predictions
    |-- client
    |   |-- __init__.py
    |   |-- __pycache__
    |   |   `-- __init__.cpython-37.pyc
    |-- scripts
    |   |-- automatic_pipeline.py
    |   |-- generate_map_user.py
    |   |-- generate_reports.py
    |   |-- launch_slad_from_slack.py
```

loan_prediction/pipeline/analysis/**init**.py -

```
from .analysis_tracker import AnalysisTrackerOccultation
```

PYTHONPATH -

```
PYTHONPATH=:/home/varshini/src/loan-prediction
```

given all the set up existing already,

VSCode is not recognizing the definition of AnalysisTrackerDefaulter from 'loan_prediction.pipeline'

spoc_occultation/scripts/automatic_pipeline.py -

```
from loan_prediction.pipeline import AnalysisTrackerDefaulter
```

I already tried -

1. Setting PYTHONPATH (as mentioned above)
2. Setting the Python Language Server to Pylance

Note: Go to Definition (Cmd + Enter) - works for directly referred paths, but in cases like above it is unable to resolve the corresponding definition. It is making my code navigation difficult?

You suggestions to resolve this would be greatly helpful.

Comment: Can you try to set the Python analysis extraPaths in VS Code settings. Which should be like `"python.analysis.extraPaths": ["/home/varshini/src/loan-predictions"]` in your `settings.json`.